# how to find a default port programmed value in atmega32?

Tags: atmega

If the ports of the microcontroller are defined as inputs and the base is not connected to the circuit somewhere
What is the default logical mode of that base (zero or one?) Is it possible to change this state
There is? How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My default, ATmega AVR pins are in a state known as *high-impedance*, which means there is no default voltage.  If you do not connect any output to a high-impedance input, we say the pin is *floating*, and the pin could easily read high or low; you cannot count on it being a particular value.

Every pin has an internal pull-up resistor that you can enable.  The pull-up resistor weakly pulls the line up, so that when nothing is driving it, its digital input value will be 1.  If you enable the pull-up resistor, the line will no longer be high-impedance or floating.

For example, to set PD2 as an input and enable its pull-up, you can use this C code:

```
DDRD &= ~(1 << 2);
PORTD |= (1 << 2);
```

Comment: thanks it was helpful i can use your way to reach what i want